# how can i make popup login window similar as on istore in objective-C/cocoa-touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, popupwindow

Hi is there any library or special view in cocoa touch which help to create a popup window like when the istore ask you for your password and name?or is it transparent view with image 2 textfields and 2 buttons?
I need it because i want to make my login screen similar.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a view that looks similar, your best bet is probably to create a UIAlertView subclass. You could create your own subclass and add the required elements.

Create a UIAlertView subclass like this in the header:

```
@interface LoginView : UIAlertView {
    // instance vars
}

// methods and properties 

@end
```

*As for the implementation of LoginView, please keep in mind the following ...*

In order to resize the UIAlertView to fit your contents (buttons, labels), you'd have to set the message text to some amount of empty lines, e.g. you could add 5 empty lines by doing the following on your UIAlertView subclass:

```
// This is a subclass of UIAlertView 
@implementation LoginView

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        // add as many newlines as you need to fit
        // the controls (buttons, labels, etc...)
        [self setMessage: @"\n\n\n\n\n"]; 

        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 30.0f);
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setText:@"Username:"];
        [self addSubview:label]
        [label release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

^ Just add buttons and labels like on any other UIView. Create an instance of this view and call the *-show* method to display the view, e.g.:

```
#import "LoginView.h"

- (void)displayLogin 
{
    LoginView *loginView = [[[LoginView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [loginView show];
}
```

To make the LoginView more flexible, create a custom initializer which accepts a target (of type *id*) and selector (of type *SEL*). When someone presses the login button, make it use the target and selector to perform the actual login. Or put the login code in the LoginView itself and create a delegate that informs the caller whether a login was successful.

This approach is kind of 'hacky' with the empty line stuff, but the result looks very nice :)

**P.S.:** remember that when you create a view like this, you shouldn't call *-setMessage:* on the instance, as it will reset the size (frame) of the view (or override *setMessage:* on the subclass to prevent resizing). If you need some label to write text on, create your own label and add it as a subview.

Comment: hi it helped i found http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UIAlertView.html but now i do not understand why i can not add 6 or more linebreaks, because if i do so it throws me out big white view.

Comment: Well, I guess if you followed the tutorial then you didn't create a subclass, there might be a few limitations if you do it like that. I suggest you try to _create a subclass_ like in my code example and in the **-init:** method set the message text to how many lines you need to fit the controls. I can add at least 10 lines (just tested it myself).

Comment: apple will reject your app if you add text field to alertview

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your own view controller dude